# Running gradle release on gitlab pipeline triggers 3 more build jobs

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-pipelines

This is my gitlab pipeline:

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: gitlab-ci

before_script:
  - git remote set-url origin https://gitlab-ci-token:$CICD_GIT_TOKEN@$CI_SERVER_HOST/$CI_PROJECT_PATH.git
  - git config --global user.email 'me@email.com'
  - git config --global user.name 'Gitlab (Me)'
  - git checkout -b $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH

stages:
  - build
  - package
  - deploy

gradle-build:
  image: gradle:alpine
  stage: build
  script:
    - PROJECT_VERSION=`./gradlew -quiet printVersion`
    - ./gradlew release
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/libs/*.jar

docker-build:
  stage: package
  script:
  - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/me/myproject:$PROJECT_VERSION .
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
  - docker push registry.gitlab.com/me/myproject:PROJECT_VERSION
```

Not sure why the 3 builds get triggered (maybe because the plugin does a commit) and not sure how to fix this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: there is no `rules` to limit the action, so every commit will trigger the jobs

Comment: @Ôrel there actually is one, and it's called exactly "rules"

Answer (score 1):

After taking a look here:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/

I added the following section to the pipeline:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_AUTHOR =~ /^Gitlab Pipeline/
      when: never
    - when: always
```

Moved the stuff in "before_script" under script, and changed the git username:

```
  script:
    - git remote set-url origin https://gitlab-ci-token:$CICD_GIT_TOKEN@$CI_SERVER_HOST/$CI_PROJECT_PATH.git
    - git config --global user.email 'me@email.com'
    - git config --global user.name 'Gitlab Pipeline'
    - git checkout -b $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    - ./gradlew release
```

Now the commits with the name "Gitlab Pipeline" don't trigger a build anymore.

The extra builds were triggered because the release plugin also does a pre-tag commit, followed by a new version commit at the end. This would trigger 2 builds, which in turn would each trigger 2 more and so on.

Now the pipeline behaves as expected.